# Shopify Storefront API 2020-10 (latest) can't fetch quantityAvailable (GraphQL)

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

For the first time I'm working with Shopify Storefront API (v. 2020-10, latest) and trying out GraphQL (I'm used to REST).

I'm able to get all the products, but if I add the field "quantityAvailable" an error occur:

*Field 'quantityAvailable' doesn't exist on type 'ProductVariant'*

I'm following the [docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/products/productvariant#fields-2020-10) where the field is listed,
can you help me understand what am I doing wrong?

[image: GraphQL Query]

Edit #1
I've already enabled "Read inventory of products and their variants" in Storefront API Permissions.

Edit #2
I'm sending a POST request to https://{my-shopify-website}/api/graphql attaching content-type and X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token as header

Comment: Are you using `/api/2020-10/graphql` or `/api/graphql` end-point? The unstable seems to have issues and doesn't include `quantityAvailable` but the `/api/2020-10/graphql` includes it.

Comment: I'm sending a POST request to https://{my-shopify-website}/api/graphql attaching content-type and X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token as header

Comment: Using https://{my-shopify-website}/api/2020-10/graphql.json it works! Please post it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `/api/2020-10/graphql` end-point allows the usage of `quantityAvailable` property, but using the unstable end-point `/api/graphql` doesn't.

This seems more like a Shopify docs or API bug/issue, but the solution is to use the specific version end-point (`/api/2020-10/graphql`) instead of the unstable one.